# If close date "Month" is Jan, then field equal oppty amount

Tags: formula, opportunity

Trying to create a formula field that will populate the opportunity dollar value if the month in the close date is January. I tried a few things but its not working. I tried putting "January" as well.

```
IF(  CloseDate = MONTH(01),  Amount * 0.5 , 0)
```

Error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'MONTH()'. Expected Date,
>   received Number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MONTH function needs to go around your date field, like this

```
IF( MONTH(CloseDate) = 1, Amount * 0.5 , 0)
```

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked!